# How to add advertisment in iPhone application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile, ads

I have a request from a client that wants to add adverisments in an iPhone application.

The client should be able to put his own advertisments at his own will: whenever his wants and as many times as his wants, without our help.

Is there any solution and what is it? Preferrably for free.
What dimensions should the banner have?

Comment: I heard that iAd itself have option to use your own ads but not sure if we can just only use our own ad?

Answer (score 1):

you can develop an xml based adv system and C# desktop app to desing adv easly. You should define properties, image and text tags, coords and navigation urls. Then an xml parser and you can create adv dynamicly.
Once i developed something like that to develop ITV channels and it reduced development time too much.
Or you can simply use webview

Answer (score 1):

Give [AdMob](http://admob.com) a try and be sure to check out House Ads.

You can use House Ads to upload/create your own banners or text ads and get the statistics and a robust framework for displaying ads in your app with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [StorageRoom](http://storageroomapp.com) to manage the ads and then use the API to pull them into your app.

Disclaimer: It's my startup.

Answer (score 0):

I've used quite a few ad networks and for what you outline as your requirements I'd go with [MobClix](http://www.MobClix.com). If you want to  earn revenue from other peoples ads then [iAds](http://advertising.apple.com/) and [MobFox](http://www.mobfox.com/) work best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adwhirl its quite flexible allowing you/client to set the ad providers, percentage per provider and as well as house ads.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you use a CMS for image upload, create some templates that use banners and create html-links, html-text, html/css/js/whatever-content.

Your app could then call specific URLs and if it gets get a valid response, it could create a UIWebView and add that to the view hierarchy.

If your user clicks the ad, the UIWebView-delegate will be called and you can decide what you want to do (e.g. open safari with the URL defined by the HTML-Link).